# Visual Studio C++ Project and Referenced Project's References

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm trying to setup a C++ solution that has multiple projects, for simplicity I'll call them `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`.

`ProjectB` is setup as a *Static Library* and uses an external library, I'll call it `ExternalLib`, that's been added to the *Additional Includes* in the properties of `ProjectB`. `ProjectA` has `ProjectB` added as a reference and has been added to the *Additional Includes* section of `ProjectA`. So far so good, I can reference classes in `ProjectB` from `ProjectA` but when I go to compile I get an error that one of the headers from `ExternalLib` can't be found. Not sure how to proceed I added `ExternalLib` to the *Additional Includes* section of `ProjectA` and built again. Now I get unresolved externals for classes in `ExternalLib`.

I'm sure I could fix the unresolved externals by adding `ExternalLib` to the *Additional Dependencies* for the Linker of `PorjectA`. However, I'm confused as to whether that's the right way to handle this. I'm a little new to C++ projects in VS, I'm more familiar with C#, so my question is:

**Is it standard to have to include a referenced project's (`ProjectB`) dependencies (`ExternalLib`) in my main project (`ProjectA`)? Or have I configured `PorjectB` incorrectly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your ProjectB header files, if header files included by ProjectA reference anything from ExternalLib then ProjectA will need to be told about ExternalLib. Usually I find the problem is that ProjectB is only supposed to use ExternalLib internally but that some part of ExternalLib has snuck into the public face of ProjectB. If something from ExternalLib is indeed supposed to be part of the public face of ProjectB then yes, anything that uses ProjectB will also need to be told about ExternalLib (ProjectB's knowledge of ExternalLib is not inherited by projects that reference ProjectB).

Comment: That's definitely it, one of the header files has references to `ExternalLib`. I was thinking that because they were private that would be ok but that doesn't matter. I'll either just have to accept I need to add references to `ExternalLib` to `ProjectA` or find some other way of exposing classes in `PorjectB` without also exposing `ExternalLib`. Thanks!

Comment: As long as ExternalLib types are not needed by ProjectA but are by the types ProjectB exposes I find the pimpl idiom an excellent answer to this problem. Basically have ProjectB expose very thin wrappers around the types that actually know about ExternalLib.